# How to ensure location updates continue indefinitely?

Tags: android, android-location

The app is handling location updates and sending the location back to a server. The app does not turn the location updates off. This is for devices permanently plugged into power, so battery is not an issue.

By design, will the location updates continue indefinitely, or will Android stop sending them at some point, for example if the app is pushed out of RAM?

If the location updates do stop, how do I request them in such a way that they will continue indefinitely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if phone is not asleep, then user processes will run.

Register a `LocationListener` in a Service so that it's triggered when location changes. Even if your service is not running, system will start it and execute the registered method.

You should definitelly read the [Deep Dive into Location](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) blog for all angles of location handling in Android.

Comment: +1 for `LocationListener`, this is a better way to handle your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are running the app.  As long as the app maintains focus, unless something catastrophic happens, it will continue to send updates.  If the app loses focus, then you might run into issues, depending on how you implement the location updating.  Either way, be sure to

- Create an `ASyncTask`[[docs]](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to handle the actual sending of updates, otherwise your app will be [killed](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)
- If the app can lose focus, you can create a Service, and detach it from your application to keep it running in the background.